# limiting checkbox checks via jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a twitter boosttrap Q and A style quiz with options, and I would like to limit the number (variable) of answers for this.

This codepen does a good job of explaining the problem: https://codepen.io/vjandrei/pen/rAuam

However, I would like to restrict this to  a set of `name` attributes. So instead of:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check1" id="check1" >
<label class="layout" for="check1"></label>

<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check2" id="check2" >
<label class="layout" for="check2"></label>

<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check3" id="check3" >
<label class="layout" for="check3"></label>
```

Id like the Jquery to operate only on `checkbox` with a certain name attribute (because there are other checkboxes in the page with different name attribite):

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="ok" id="check1" >
<label class="layout" for="check1"></label>

<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="ok" id="check2" >
<label class="layout" for="check2"></label>

<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="ok" id="check3" >
<label class="layout" for="check3"></label>
```

and I would like to write something like this in Jquery:

```
$("input:checkbox[name="ok"]").click(function() {
var bol = $("input:checkbox[name="ok"]:checked").length >= 2;     
$("input:checkbox[name="ok"]").not(":checked").attr("disabled",bol);
});
```

However the above ^ does not work for me (apologies, new to JQuery here).. and I was wondering how I can restrcit the selection of checkboxes restrcited to elements with certain names.

Comment: Your bottom snippet is reducing the click handler to those with a name of "ok", but your inner `bol` logic is looking at all checkboxes that are checked, regardless of name.  See a problem?

Comment: @Taplar: I completely see it, but when I add the `[name="ok"]` I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` in codepen. So, I assumed that something is not right with the syntax/how I am trying to get checkboxes with a certain attribute. See my problem? :) PS: I have edited the last snip, but it throws me the error on codepen.

Comment: If multiple groups need to be constrained in this way, then you will find it a pain to code each group separately, by name. If possible, you should allow for rule-based selection of the groups - eg have each group bounded by a containing html element.

Comment: You have a syntax error because the delimiter for your selector is double quotes.  So since you are trying to use double quotes inside the string as well, you are incorrectly terminating the string too soon.  The simpliest approach to fixing that is to use single quotes around the `'ok'`.  Otherwise you can escape the inner double quotes that should be considered as literals, not delimiters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to qualify the checkboxes with their `name` attribute so that you only count the checkboxes in a given group when you run your event handler. Note that since the `[name="ok"]` includes double quotes you need to put the selector as a whole into single quotes. Also, for groups which don't all have the same name (e.g. `check1`, `check2` and `check3` in your first snippet) you need to use a "starts with" selector on `name` e.g. `name^="check"`:

```js
$('input:checkbox[name^="check"]').click(function() {
  var bol = $('input:checkbox[name^="check"]:checked').length >= 2;
  $('input:checkbox[name^="check"]').not(":checked").attr("disabled", bol);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check1" id="check1">
<label class="layout" for="check1"></label>

<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check2" id="check2">
<label class="layout" for="check2"></label>

<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check3" id="check3">
<label class="layout" for="check3"></label>
```